# How many cards should I draw with Potion of Luck?

Tags: flesh-and-blood

The Potion of Luck says: "Instant — Destroy Potion of Luck: Shuffle your hand and arsenal into your deck, then draw that many cards". Say, I've got 4 cards in hand and one in the arsenal. Do I draw 4 or 5 cards?

[image]